# D3 force directed layout distribute across X axis

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Playing with D3 [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) for graphs I've noted that result always tends to circle form. But there are lot of empty space in horizontal margins. My question - how to allow layout distribute objects more in width than in height. My naive try just to modify `tick` to give less rate (`0.99`) for `y` was failed:

```
    function tick() {
      path.attr("d", linkArc);
      circle
        .attr("cx", function(d) { 
            return d.x = Math.max(R, Math.min(width - R, d.x)); }) 
        .attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return d.y = Math.max(R, Math.min(height - R, d.y*0.99)); }); 

      text.attr("transform", transform);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter that controls the circular placement is [`.gravity()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#gravity). This force pulls nodes towards the center. You can disable it by setting the value to 0. If you do that, you should use something else to ensure that the nodes are not leaving the canvas, e.g. as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492).

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the key code for this functionality should be in pick().

I don't have all code for your example, but I will present to you 2 examples that achieve different behavior on X and Y axis.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/Wt6Wv/) you just look for lines that contain `.5625`, thats all you need to get your diagram squeezed.

And in this another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/pr784/) you can see the diagram completely smashed, with smaller constant. :)